# Realm + Swift, nested JSON

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, realm

I have a problem since last 2 days. I can't get my JSON transformed to a Realm Object.

I have a json like below:

```
{
  "gender" : "male",
  "id" : "123456789",
  "age_range" : {
    "min" : 21
  },
  "last_name" : "LastName" 
}
```

I have this Realm Models:

```
class UserObject: Object {

    dynamic var userId: String = ""
    dynamic var lastName: String?
    dynamic var gender: String?
    var ageRange = List<AgeRangeObject>()

    required convenience init?(_ map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }
}

class AgeRangeObject: Object {

    dynamic var min: Int = 0
}
```

And the way I am trying to create an instance of this model with ObjectMapper to parse json to dictionary and then create the model instance:

```
    let userJSONModel = Mapper<User>().map(jsonString)

    let realm = try! Realm()

    do {
        try realm.write {

            let dict: [String : AnyObject] = [
                "userId" : (userJSONModel?.userId)!,
                "ageRange" : (userJSONModel?.ageRange)!,
                "lastName" : (userJSONModel?.lastName)!,
                "gender" : (userJSONModel?.gender)!
            ]

            let userModel = UserObject(value: dict)

            realm.add(userModel)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Exception")
    }
```

The problem occurs on this line: `let userModel = UserObject(value: dict)`

I get the folowing error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Invalid value 'min' to initialize object of type 'AgeRangeObject': missing key 'min''
```

I was looking on the stackoverflow:

[Nested Arrays throwing error in realm.create(value: JSON) for Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36990181/nested-arrays-throwing-error-in-realm-createvalue-json-for-swift)

[How to convert Realm object to JSON with nested NSDate properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37669769/how-to-convert-realm-object-to-json-with-nested-nsdate-properties)

but my case is different. 
Do you know what's the problem with that age range dictionary? Why it can't parse it well?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your JSON, `ageRange` is a dictionary, whereas the `UserObject.ageRange` property is a `List<AgeRangeObject>`. You have mismatched models.

You either need to update your models to reflect the structure of your JSON:

```
var ageRange = List<AgeRangeObject>()
```

becomes

```
dynamic var ageRange: AgeRangeObject? = nil
```

or vice versa, update your JSON to reflect the structure of your models:

```
{
  "gender" : "male",
  "id" : "123456789",
  "age_range" : [{
    "min" : 21
  }],
  "last_name" : "LastName" 
}
```

Comment: thank you a lot! :) Now I am enlightened ;) I think that the Realm documentation isn't clear about this case.

Comment: How to Update age_range dictionary to List Object

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "key1" : "value1",
  "key2" : "value2",
  "array1" : [{
    "key" : value
  }],
 "key3" : "value3" 
}
```

For this you could use ObjectMapper's TransformType.

Reference: https://github.com/APUtils/ObjectMapperAdditions

My Code:

```
@objcMembers class RealmObject: Object, Mappable {

  dynamic var listValues = List<MyRealmObject>()

  required convenience init?(map: Map) {
    self.init()
  }

 // Mappable
 func mapping(map: Map) {
   listValues <- (map["listValues"], RealmlistObjectTransform())
  }

}

@objcMembers class MyRealmObject: Object, Mappable {

    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
      self.init()
    }

    // Mappable
    func mapping(map: Map) {

    }
  }

class RealmlistObjectTransform: TransformType {
    typealias Object = List<MyRealmObject> // My Realm Object here
    typealias JSON = [[String: Any]] // Dictionary here

    func transformFromJSON(_ value: Any?) -> List<MyRealmObject>? {
      let list = List<MyRealmObject>()
      if let actors = value as? [[String: Any]]  {
        let objects = Array<MyRealmObject>(JSONArray: actors)
        list.append(objectsIn: objects)
      }
      return list
    }

    func transformToJSON(_ value: List<MyRealmObject>?) -> [[String: Any]]? {
      if let actors = value?.sorted(byKeyPath: "").toArray(ofType: MyRealmObject.self).toJSON() {
        return actors
      }
      return nil
    }
  }
```